# How to make context array for set socks 5 or http proxy for php stream_socket_client

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, proxy

I am not sure how can I configure stream context parameter for tcp proxy for streaming socket in php. I found and tested following code but it's not working for stream sockect.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
            array(
              'http'=>array(
                'proxy'=> 'tcp://'.$proxy,                
                )
              )
            );
$srvHandle = stream_socket_client("tcp://{$this->server}", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
if ($srvHandle === false)
   $this->LogError("failed to connect with host website, check your network connection.");
stream_set_blocking($srvHandle, true);
stream_socket_enable_crypto($srvHandle, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
stream_set_blocking($srvHandle, false);
```

But the context is working for file_get_contents function.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
            array(
              /*
              'socket' => array(
                  'bindto' => $proxy,
                  )    
              */
              'http'=>array(
                'proxy'=> 'tcp://'.$proxy,
                "request_fulluri" => TRUE,
                ),
              "ssl"  => array(
                "SNI_enabled" => FALSE,
                )
              )
            );

$result =  file_get_contents("http://api.ipify.org?format=json", false, $context);
```

So I can know the context only working for http protocol.

How can I configure the context parameter array for tcp stream socket?

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams, as per your example you need a client stream socket.

Look at [stream_socket_client](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) to create a tcp socket. Note the last parameter, `$context`, that should be created using [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

There are examples enough in manuals, but here it is on how to use it

```
$context = stream_context_create(
            array(
              /*
              'socket' => array(
                  'bindto' => $proxy,
                  )    
              */
              'http'=>array(
                'proxy'=> 'tcp://'.$proxy,
                "request_fulluri" => TRUE,
                ),
              "ssl"  => array(
                "SNI_enabled" => FALSE,
                )
              )
            );

$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://www.example.com:80", $errno, $errstr, 30, ini_get("default_socket_timeout"), STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

Also note that [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) also accepts the context, and works with tcp streams too. The stream extension functions provide more options, but for basic use `fopen` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The proxy context is completely ignored by stream_socket_client() http://php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php

Comment: @tim I couldn't find anything on that page or `stream_socket_client` about ignoring proxy in context. Can you point it?

Comment: The page lists what parameters are supported. I just tried setting a value for proxy and it was completely ignored in PHP 7.2.

Comment: @tim I see. I don't remember using it, so maybe you are right. Thanks!